# Default value/dealing with empty values when using the ItemLoader in Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm using the itemloader to process my scraped data, and, in order to maintain the structure and integrity of the original data, and to allow for easy database insertion, I need to store the empty values that my XPaths sometimes come up with.

The problem is, however, that there seems to be no simple way of doing this using the itemloader, as None-types don't even seem to reach the input processor.

For simplicity, consider trying to add two values of type None to an item like follows:

```
loader.add_value('name', None)
loader.add_value('name', None)
```

The item will not be affected at all by these two lines. This is not the behavior I want. Instead, I would like there to be two (new) elements in `item['name']` like `["",""]`

I modified the `_add_value()` and `load_item()` methods of the `ItemLoader` class like this:

```
def _add_value(self, field_name, value):
    value = arg_to_iter(value)
    processed_value = self._process_input_value(field_name, value)
    self._values.setdefault(field_name, [])
    self._values[field_name] += arg_to_iter(processed_value)

def load_item(self):
        adapter = ItemAdapter(self.item)
        for field_name in tuple(self._values):
            value = self.get_output_value(field_name)
            if value:
                adapter[field_name] = value
            else: 
                adapter[field_name] = "NA"
        return adapter.item
```

This at least prevents the empty fields, but I have no idea what problems might arise from doing this, and it doesn't really solve my problem, since I want to store **all** empty data.

One solution is of course to simply not use the itemloader, and instead just check if the value of `response.xpath()` is null. However,that would cause my project to become a lot messier, which I would like to avoid if possible.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [dataclass](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#working-with-dataclass-items) or [attr.s](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html?highlight=scrapy.Field#attr-s-objects) items, and set a default value:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field


@dataclass
class QuoteItem:
    text: str = field(default=None)
    author: str = field(default=None)
    tags: list = field(default=None)
    emp: str = field(default="NA")
```

you have to also change `emp`'s output_processor to take the second value:

```
from itemloaders.processors import TakeFirst
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader


def take_second(value):
    if len(value) > 1:
        return value[1]

class QuoteLoader(ItemLoader):
    text_out = TakeFirst()
    author_out = TakeFirst()
    emp_out = take_second
```

Comment: Unless I'm doing something wrong, this doesn't work. Although it can populate empty fields, it doesn't retain ALL the None values, only the first. The problem, as I mentioned in my original post, seems to be that the result of add_* methods don't even reach the itemloader if it's empty/None.

Comment: Update: I managed to get it working for my particular case using dataclass items as you suggested, by creating a new item for every loop and adding them all to my "main" item. Coincidentally, this also created a better structure for my data. I'm not sure if it would be a good solution to the problem in general however

Comment: @Lobs001 That's great. Maybe we should look for a similar issue in the scrapy repo or start a new one, because i definitely didn't expect this behaviour  (ignoring Nones).